# Is it possible to create a .xcarchive directly within from XCode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode

Many iterations ago XCode used to have a direct command to create an .xcarchive, now its gone.

Googling this for other answer people answer about creating an .ipa, but an ipa is not the same as a .xcarchive.

Is it possible to create an .xcarchive from XCode or must it be done using command line tools?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xcode still supports this just as it always has. All you need to do is archive your target (Product -> Archive). That's it. You will find the `.xcarchive` file in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives`.

Comment: Yep - this hasn't changed in the past couple major versions, as far as I can remember.